# Is there a cross-browser way for tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, tooltip, d3.js

I am working with d3.js for rendering my graphs. For some reason, I am not a huge fan of svg title because of the delay it incurs and the inability to style them. Please do correct me if I am wrong. I recently came across, [tipsy](https://raw.github.com/bigmlcom/tipsy/master/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js) but it does not seem to be cross-browser compatible.

For instance, consider [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/Docudocker/setups/tipsyCrashingApplication/force-html.html). The tooltips work just fine in Firefox and Chrome but do not appear even in IE 9 and I'm not sure what's going on. Is there a cleaner cross-browser approach for tooltips compatible with d3.js other than using the `svg title` attribute?

**EDIT**: I am looking for something that works with d3.js. For instance, using tipsy, we do the following:

`$("svg circle").tipsy({});`

This works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE. Similar thing was observed when using the tooltip plugin of Twitter's Bootstrap. Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Legend/bZY9e/) *without* the tooltip added to enable quick tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for. I haven't tested it in IE9 but I would imagine it works.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: +1 Thank you. Works with my bugfix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147830/can-someone-comment-on-my-bug-fix

Answer (score 4):

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) is a good plugin for cross-platform tooltips.

JQueryUI 1.9 will soon be [adding support for tooltips](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip).

Comment: +1 Thank you. Would you have any idea if this would be compatible with d3? Please look at my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Tooltip is lightweight and have a nice compability, i've got good results in projects where i used it.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/