# Can someone comment on my bug fix?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using [Twitter's Bootstrap Tooltip plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips). This works perfectly fine except that when used on `svg` elements, it breaks. After some debugging, I narrowed down the problem. In the `js` file, the `init` function looks like this:

```
  , init: function (type, element, options) {
      var eventIn
        , eventOut

      ...

      if (this.options.trigger != 'manual') {
        eventIn  = this.options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focus'
        eventOut = this.options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur'
        this.$element.on(eventIn, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.enter, this))
        this.$element.on(eventOut, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.leave, this))
      }

      ...

    }
```

I remembered there were numerous issues with SVG-IE 9.0 specific implementation so I made the following modifications:

```
  if (this.options.trigger != 'manual') {
    eventIn  = this.options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focus'
    eventOut = this.options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur'
    var flag = $.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 9
    eventIn = flag ? "mouseover" : eventIn
    eventOut = flag ? "mouseout" : eventOut

    this.$element.on(eventIn, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.enter, this))
    this.$element.on(eventOut, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.leave, this))
  }
```

And this works fine in all browsers. After some searching, I found that [someone else](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-6-2-broke-svg-hover-events#14737000002851960) faced the same problem. I am not sure if there is a better way of fixing this bug especially after reading the argument in the [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-6-2-broke-svg-hover-events#14737000002851960).

> In IE9, there is a native contains() implementation on the document,
>   so jQuery uses it. The problem is that this contains() implementation
>   does not extend to SVG elements.

Any suggestions on whether my fix can be improved?

Comment: This seems like a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I might have some suggestions but the best thing is to go on the [bootstrap github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) and do a pull request and @fat and @mdo will certainly take a look at it before merging your code in and even give you feedback. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Thank you. I will do as you suggested.